# Format text in Xamarin Binding expression

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I may not have explained it fully in the topic title, but what I actually want to do is the following:

```xml
<Label Text="Order Remaining :" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
<Label Text="{Binding RemainingAmount}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></Label>
```

What I want to come across in the code I mentioned above is this:

Order Remaining :   120 **amount**

As you can see here, I can't add the word "amount", can I do something like `{Binding RemaininAmount + 'Amount'}` without creating another Label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StringFormat` in the Binding expression like so:

```xml
<Label Text="Order Remaining :" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
<Label Text="{Binding RemainingAmount, StringFormat='{0:d} amount'}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
```

The `{0:d}` means that you're formatting a string where the first *(and only)* argument is supposed to be displayed as a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this , add Grid.Row and Column to Label

```
 <Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
 <Span Text="Order Remaining :"/>
            <Span Text=" "/>
            <Span Text="{Binding RemainingAmount}"/>
            <Span Text=" "/>
            <Span Text="amount"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002948#format-strings

Comment: nice method thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use the [StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/string-formatting) to achieve this.

```
 <Label Text="{Binding RemainingAmount, StringFormat='Order Remaining : {0:d}amount'}" />
```

Second, you can write the code in the xaml.cs file.

```
<Label x:Name= "Mylabel" />

Mylabel.Text = $"Order Remaining : {RemainingAmount}amount";
```

Comment: Can I define variables in xml like this? This is beautiful.

Mylabel.Text = $"Order Remaining : {RemainingAmount}amount";

Comment: You can not write it in the xml file. it is wrote in the cs file.